# Get attribute of objects in an array

Tags: jquery, attr

For some reason, jQuery isn't giving me the attributes of objects in array when I define the number in the array. It will return the class of the first object in an array when none in particular are defined, though. For example, this works:

```
$('#content').prepend($('div #left ol.group li',data).attr("class"));
```

but this doesn't:

```
$('#content').prepend($('div #left ol.group li',data)[3].attr("class"));
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work like most other functions do and how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing an individual element of a jQuery set using the indexer returns a DOM object, which doesn't have the `.attr()` method. You want `.eq(3)`, which returns a jQuery object wrapping that individual element.

Answer (score 4):

with jQuery get the index by using `eq`

```
$('#content').prepend($('div #left ol.group li',data).eq(3).attr("class"));
```

Comment: This would be a +1 if you told him *why* as well as what. :-) (E.g., because when you index into the jQuery object, what you get back is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.)